# How to move multiple AD Users into multiple OUs with powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I want to move multiple users from input file to multiple OU's. But the code below keeps giving me error:

```
$i=0
$tempOUsArray = @{}
$tempOUsArray = Import-CSV -path "c:\temp\OUs.txt" #this file contains Full DN of OUs 

$UsersToBeMoved = Import-CSV -path "c:\temp\Users.txt #this file contain SamAccountName field of users

$UsersToBeMoved | ForEach-Object{

$tempUsers = (get-aduser -identity $_.Name).distinguishedName

#assign each OU to temp holder
$TempOU = $tempOUsArray[$i]

Move-ADObject -Identity $tempUsers -TargetPath $TempOU

$i++ #inclement position of array

}
```

Comment: You have to terminate the string for the `-Path` arg on `Import-Csv` like: `$UsersToBeMoved = Import-CSV -path "c:\temp\Users.txt"` If there's an error besides that please add it to the question.  Also please tell us what pattern you want to move in.  An example of the 2 CSV files would be helpful.

Comment: I think this can lead you into trouble, as there is no correlation between the users and the OU each of them has to be moved to. Better create one CSV with two columns: one for the user's SamAccountName and the other for the OU into which the uses has to be moved.

Comment: Thank you all!  I had typo with the terminating string for Users.txt line when fat-fingered here. And Thanks, Theo for the recommendation. But the errors I got are: Move-ADObject: The parameter is incorrect -> Move-ADObject -Identity $tempuser -TargetPath $TempOU..

Comment: And to answer Steven's... Yes, there are 2 csv files to be used, one is for users, other is for OUs. I want to process them both independently. Anything you recommend or make this work is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @HowardNguyen, can you provide a small sample (you can obfuscate the data if you like) of the OUs text file? Also, can you confirm that both text files have the same number of entries in them?

Comment: @Guy S -- OUs.txt has same number of items as Users.txt file. For OUs.txt, the full dn of OUs is as this:  "OU=ABC,OU=DEF,DC=test,DC=com". For Users.txt, data includes user's SamAccountName.

Answer (score 0):

(See edits for previous answer attempts, clearing to reduce answer size)

See the below. I've tested this on a setup I have and this successfully moved the objects without an issue.

Users.txt (CSV format, matching what I believe yours is)

```
samaccountname,name 
tst-user1,user1 
tst-user2,user2 
tst-user3,user3
tst-user4,user4

# (From OP: My users input file is)
# john.doe
# ann.bill
# jose.love
```

OUs.txt (no quotation marks in txt file, though may need if there's any spaces in the DN)

```
OU=test,OU=Accounts,DC=domain,DC=int
OU=test,OU=Accounts,DC=domain,DC=int
OU=test,OU=Accounts,DC=domain,DC=int
OU=test,OU=Accounts,DC=domain,DC=int
```

PS script

```
$i = 0
$OUs = @()
$OUs = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\OUs.txt
$Users = Import-Csv -Path C:\temp\Users.txt

$users | ForEach-Object {
    $tempUser = (Get-ADUser -Identity $($_.samaccountname)).DistinguishedName
    $tempOU = $OUs[$i]

    Write-Host "Moving User: [$tempUser]"
    Write-Host "   to OU: [$tempOU]"

    Move-ADObject -Identity $tempUser -TargetPath $tempOU

    $i++
}
```

Output

```
Moving User: [CN=user1,OU=source,OU=test,OU=Accounts,DC=domain,DC=int]
   to OU: [OU=test,OU=Accounts,DC=domain,DC=int]
Moving User: [CN=user2,OU=source,OU=test,OU=Accounts,DC=domain,DC=int]
   to OU: [OU=test,OU=Accounts,DC=domain,DC=int]
Moving User: [CN=user3,OU=source,OU=test,OU=Accounts,DC=domain,DC=int]
   to OU: [OU=test,OU=Accounts,DC=domain,DC=int]
Moving User: [CN=user4,OU=source,OU=test,OU=Accounts,DC=domain,DC=int]
   to OU: [OU=test,OU=Accounts,DC=domain,DC=int]
```

And all worked properly, no errors. Can you try the above code, and ensure your source files are in a similar format?

## Final edit

With the provided edit / update to the "users.txt" file, the below script should work as expected.

New users.txt file (note: no column header)

```
john.doe
ann.bill
jose.love
```

PS script

```
$i = 0
$OUs = @() # May as well clear, in case old data exists
$Users = @() # May as well clear, in case old data exists
$OUs = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\OUs.txt
$Users = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\Users.txt

$users | ForEach-Object {
    $tempUser = (Get-ADUser -Identity $($_)).DistinguishedName
    $tempOU = $OUs[$i]

    Write-Host "Moving User: [$tempUser]"
    Write-Host "   to OU: [$tempOU]"

    Move-ADObject -Identity $tempUser -TargetPath $tempOU

    $i++
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Guy S!!!  However, I got the same error as before: Move-ADObject : The operation could not be performed because the object's parent is either uninstantiated or deleted....   + Move-ADObject -Identity $tempuser -TargetPath $TempOU;   The dn & userID is correctly pulled from each run.

Comment: @HowardNguyen writing a revision now, please hold :D

Comment: @HowardNguyen done, sorry it's hard to troubleshoot without a PC with the AD module installed :D and without the source files. Think I got it this time though :)

Comment: My header is same as yours without title. However, without quotes around OUs, the $tempOU gets nothing though.

Comment: We'll leave the quotes in the file then. Do the OUs exist in AD?

Also, if you put the "Write-Host" commands in to check the DN and OU you're going to use, do they show up properly / as expected?

Comment: And without header it won't read into the $tempOUArray as well!

Comment: Yes, all the OUs exist and no special about them...just standard.

Comment: Thanks @HowardNguyen, try with the new code? Booted up my work PC to confirm it all works properly.

Comment: Thanks Guy S!!  The Users.csv or .txt should only contain 1 column with only SamAccountName of the user(s), though. like below

Comment: Same code should still work with only one column, @HowardNguyen, but if it's just the one column may as well use it as a text file with no header and import the same way as the OUs, then change `$_.samaccountname` to simply `$_`. Either way, as long as you have your answer now, happy days :)

Answer (score 0):

It is with the `Move-ADObject`. This function will NOT work with moving parts like multiple OUs assignment. My revised code is as below:

```
$i=0
$tempOUsArray = @{}    
$tempOUsArray = get-content -path "c:\temp\OUs.txt"     #this file contains Full DN of 
OUs 

$UsersToBeMoved = get-content -path "c:\temp\Users.txt"     #this file contain 
SamAccountName field of users

ForEach ($tuser in $UsersToBeMoved){    

$tempUser = dsquery user -samid $tuser    

#assign each OU to temp holder    
$TempOU = $tempOUsArray[$i]    

dsmove $tempUser -newparent $TempOU    

$i++ #inclement position of array    

}    

$tempOUArray.Clear()    
$TempOU=''    
$tempUser=''    
$tuser=''
```

Note:  Remove All Header from input files. OUs.txt with full DN in double-quotes.       `Users.txt` file contains only the SamAccountName without quotes.